# <cite> line-height won't show lower than 1em (100%) of font-size in <blockqoute>

Tags: html, css

I am working with a pre-existing theme and have the following html:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>BLOCKQUOTE TEXT</p>

  <footer>
     <cite>CITED AUTHOR</cite>
  </footer>
</blockquote>
```

The corresponding css is as follows:

```
blockquote {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    line-height: 1.8182;
}

blockquote cite {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    line-height: 1.6842;
}
```

The site does use a css reset that leaves the html (root) font-size at 10px. Therefore 1rem = 10px. The computed css would look like this:

```
blockquote {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 40.0004005432129px;
}

blockquote cite {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 31.9997997283936px;
}
```

My problem is that replacing the line-height value for cite in the above css reflects only if the line-height has a value greater than the current line-height. For example, if I were to write:

```
blockquote cite {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

The visual output still looks as if the line-height is 1.6842 (or 31.9px). Changing the line-height in the blockquote itself reflects as it should with no problems.

I'm unsure if that is enough information to determine where the problem lies, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why a cite inside a blockquote would not reflect the declared line-height, regardless of what units I use. I simply want to reduce the line-height of the cite. Please note the issue occurs across all current major browsers.

Comment: The `cite` element has `display:inline` by default, meaning that it lives in inline formatting context of the parent element, in the line box that can’t be smaller than the effective `line-height` of the parent element. Can you set the `line-height` for the `footer` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:inline-block` for the `cite` element.

```css
blockquote {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    line-height: 1.8182;
}

blockquote cite {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    line-height: .75;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>BLOCKQUOTE TEXT</p>

  <footer>
     <cite>CITED AUTHOR</cite>
  </footer>
</blockquote>
```